# Swift/iOS equivalent of spinner in Android?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to design a screen for an iOS app where a tableView cell will have a dropdown which expands onClick and contains options from some data source. Here is an image:

[image]

The Serving tableview cell is where I'm trying to add this drop down.

I'm a fairly new iOS developer, but I know in Android this would be accomplished with a Spinner. I looked into picker views but I am unsure how to insert it to appear onClick.

The tableview displayed has been implemented as a 2 section tableview. I wanted to do the top section as a static tableview but there doesn't seem to be a way to implement a static and dynamic tableview in the same viewcontroller.

Any advice on how to achieve this functionality or more information?

Comment: You can put multiple tableviews in the same controller (static and dynamic mixed) there's no restriction. 
You should put some of the code you write and ask a question in relation with something you are stuck with.

Comment: I'm stuck with not knowing what exactly I need to use to accomplish that drop down list/Spinner effect I'm looking for... There's really no code to show yet. I just needed information on the best way to accomplish something for the Serving like what is seen in the picture where you'd click the cell and get a dropdown of selections.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you  wanted to show the bottom tableview when clicking the second row, as user2437424 answered in iOS selecting in a list is made with a UIPickerView (https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerview)

Answer (score 2):

A UIPickerView is the object you're looking for.  To insert it into your interface on a click of the cell, you can implement the UITableView delegate method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` , which is called every time a table view row is selected:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == ROW_OF_CELL { //ROW_OF_CELL is index of the cell you just tapped  
    //... code to display picker view here ...
    }
}
```

And after you select your item, you can remove it and update your model using the UIPickerView delegate method `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    //... code to update your model and remove picker view here ...
}
```

There are plenty of tutorials about using UIPickerViews if you just google  them, one (of many) examples here:
http://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/